# problems in installing Karma integration tool for windows 8 64 bit machine

Tags: java, maven, karma-runner

I have installed Maven 3.0.5 on my windows 8 64 bit machine by the following steps:

Downloaded apache-maven-3.0.5.bin.zip and the archive is stored in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. I changed the environment variables as follows:
M2_HOME with value C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5
M2 with value %M2_HOME%\bin
JAVE_HOME with value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
PATH with value %M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

after this when i type mvn --version i get

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:
28+0530)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

I have downloaded JDK and JRE in the folders under
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25

Now for Karma to install I downloaded the Web-Karma-Master zip and the archive is placed under
C:\Program Files\Web-Karma-master\Web-Karma-master

Now when I type mvn clean install in this directory I get the following:

```
 ..
...
...
[INFO] karma-mr .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karma-storm ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] karma-web-services ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] web-services-rdf .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.285s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 29 13:21:14 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1 
or one of its dependencie s could not be resolved: Failed
to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:
exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact 
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.1 from/to central 

Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused: 
Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, 
re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable
 full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and 
possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException.
```

Please help. I have done all the above in the same order as mentioned. But I am not able to resolve this problem.

Archana.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?  If so, you need to configure `proxy` settings in your `settings.xml`.

Comment: yes i am behind a proxy server. What do I need to configure in settings.xml??

Comment: Added an answer with the details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `settings.xml` in `.m2` folder of your `HOME` directory.  Add the following:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>your.org</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.your.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>

</settings>
```

Remove `<username>` and `<password>` tags if your proxy server does not need authentication.
You can look for the values for these in your browser `settings`.

Also refer to  [proxies](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) section of [maven settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: m2 folder is the folder C:\program files\apache software foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5\conf folder where the original settings.xml file is placed. Correct?

Comment: No. It is a subfolder in `C:\Users\archana` (assuming your windows username is `archana`).

Comment: I have changed the required settings in the settings file xml in m2 folder. I have given the host, username, password and port (80) as per my proxy settings in the file. Now when I type mvn clean install in Web-Karma-Master directory in the command prompt I still get the same above error. What is the problem now?

Comment: `m2` or `.m2`?  Was it already created?  Did it have a `repository`  subfolder?

Comment: yes the folder was already created and it had a repository subfolder. it was .m2 folder

Comment: Any idea about how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you access `http://repo.maven.apache.org` from your browser, with proxy details configured? If so, your maven proxy configuration is incorrect.  Your sys admin can troubleshoot.  Otherwise you could share screenshots of your browser proxy configuration and the `settings.xml` that you added... also check if the file is `settings.xml` and not `settings.xml.txt`

Comment: For the above link I get a message

Comment: For the above link I get a message Browsing for this directory has been disabled.
View this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead. When i put this link: http://search.maven.org/#browse I am directed to the Central Repository Browser. The file is settings.xml not settings.xml.txt.

Comment: My settings.xml in .m2 repository has the following comments: <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>archana.kumar</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
      <host>mahe.manipal.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

Comment: The proxy settings for my system are: Proxy server ip address 172.16.19.10 with port 80. The proxy server is bypassed for local addresses

Comment: In `settings.xml` `host` should be the ip address of the `proxy server`.

Comment: Yes it has now downloaded. Thanks a lot.But after downloading it has given the following error.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project karma-util: Fatal error compiling: direct
ory not found: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\ka
rma-util\target\classes -> [Help 1]

Comment: In C: Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-mven-3.2.3\karma-util\ is there but there is no target\classes directory. Do i need to create it?

Comment: Can anyone help me with the problem

Comment: This is an issue different from your original problem.  Please ask a different question with relevant details so that someone can help.  If the above answer helped for your original question, accept the answer.